# Updating local kernel repository using GIT

Tags: git

Earlier I have downloaded Linux kernel from the git repository.
Now I am trying to update it using git pull, but it only updates to kernel version v2.6.36.4.
After that the git pull command start giving message "Already up-to-date."

However, I can see that the latest version on git repository is 2.6.39-rc2.
How can I get that without using the git clone once gain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are in the correct branch? You can find out which remote branches there are by using:

```
git branch -r
```

You can then track these with:

```
git checkout --track -b <local_branchname> origin/<remote_branchname>
```

More info can be found [here](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/09/checkout-remote-tracked-branch.html).